# How to make payment of google developer console license fee without credit/debit card

Tags: google-developers-console

We are from india and we do not have a credit card. The debit card we carry cannot make international transactions. What's the other way to make the payment of one time license fee of google developer console without two above cited options.Is there any alternative mode of payment.